# Extend line spacing for two rows of enumerate items when combined with itemjoin

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize, line-spacing, inline

**Problem:**

I wish to extend the line spacing for an enumerate list that divides over two rows when using `itemjoin`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}[0pt]{0.2\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate*}[\bfseries\alph*), itemjoin=\qquad]
        \item $\sqrt{\dfrac{x^{3}}{x}}$
        \item $\dfrac{3 x}{\sqrt{x^{2}}}$
        \item $\dfrac{(\sqrt{x})^{2}}{x^{2}}$
        \item $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^{4}-x^{2}}}{x}$
        \item $\dfrac{1-x}{|x-1|}$
        \item $\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x}$
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{addmargin}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To have line spacing between the first (a to e) and second row (f).

Comment: Do you really want to use  the enumerate* environment for that?

Comment: @Bernard What do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: The `tasks` package, or `shortlist`(but you'll have to install the latter by yourself, as it is not in TeX Live nor MiKTeX for licensing reasons).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have no problem with the `tasks` package, if you replace the `addmargin` environment with `geometry (which will give you more sensible margins if you don't use margin notes). Furthermore the items on different rows will be aligned in columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tasks}[label-format=\bfseries](5)%, label-width=1.5em](5)%[\bfseries\alph*), itemjoin=\qquad]
        \task $\sqrt{\dfrac{x^{3}}{x}}$
        \task $\dfrac{3 x}{\sqrt{x^{2}}}$
        \task $\dfrac{(\sqrt{x})^{2}}{x^{2}}$
        \task $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^{4}-x^{2}}}{x}$
        \task $\dfrac{1-x}{|x-1|}$
        \task $\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x}$
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]